# COM registration with WIX in 32bit and 64bit Windows

Tags: com, windows-7, wix

I created an installer for my AnyCPU DLLs. I've marked my assemblies with teh Assembly=.net directive in my project as well. The installer seems to be able to register the COM servers successfully on my XP 32bit machine, but fails to do so in my Windows7 Machine. I did run the installer in admin mode. Also I looked up the Win764 registry and found those CLSIDs in the reigstry. So looks like the MSI did put some entries in the registry but somehow they are not being recognized as valid COM Server entries (OLE Viewer also didnt enumerate my server).

Any idea why this would happen? Any extra config do I need to add to my project?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to compile your msi as a 64-bit native binary to have the dlls registered in 64 bit mode.